# Dockerized microservice could not register to eureka server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

I am using spring boot, spring cloud netfix and docker to run microservices.

Everything is fine in non-dockerized environments, but once I dockerized the eureka server and the microservice, for example user-service, I found that the user-service could not registered to eureka server.

I can access to both the dockerized eureka server via http://{Ubuntu server}:8761/eureka/, or dockerized service via http://{Ubuntu server}:8088/user-service.

But in the docker-compose log, i found the error [see the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvnrz.png)
I am not sure why it kept said that unknown server.

And in the eureka server website, there is no application instance shown. This error message already confused me for several days, and I already investigate every possibility that i could think out. Please advice me any clue on it. thank you.

Background:

```
Virtualbox: 5.1.20

Ubuntu VM: ubuntu-16

docker installed: 17.06.0

Registry: localhost:5000

Network: Bridge mode in Virtualbox for Ubuntu VM, so that the VM has a standalone ip that could be accessed by other computer
```

Eureka Server configuration:

```
server:
  port: ${vcap.application.port:8761} #Http port

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka
    #prefer-ip-address:true

  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/
  #server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Microservice configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    ## Define the service name for registering on Eureka
    name: user-service
  profiles: docker

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:8761/eureka/
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}

endpoints:
    restart:
      enabled: true
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
    health:
      sensitive: true
```

Docker compose:

```
discovery-eureka:
  image: localhost:5000/nicolas/eureka:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
  hostname: eureka

user-service:
  image: localhost:5000/nicolas/user:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
  - "8088:8088"
  links:
  - discovery-eureka
```

Comment: can you ping the eureka container from within the user-service. `docker exec -it user-service bash` and then  `ping eureka`

Comment: @yamenk, thank you for your reply, yes ping to eureka container from within user-service got response successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, the magic thing is the spring profiles definition in application.yml of user service.

i overlooked this definition from the beginning, my docker-compose.yml definition before:

```
discovery-eureka:
  image: localhost:5000/nicolas/eureka:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
  - "8761:8761"
  hostname: eureka

user-service:
  image: localhost:5000/nicolas/user:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
  - "8088:8088"
  links:
  - discovery-eureka
```

From this file, there is no place to tell container(or JVM) to use the docker profile defined in application.yml of user service.

Once the container is initialized, it will use default profile and the metadata in application.yml will not be popularized.

Afterwards i changed the docker-compose.yml to below, everything works.

```
discovery-eureka:
  image: localhost:5000/nicolas/eureka:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
  - "8761:8761"
  hostname: eureka

user-service:
  image: localhost:5000/nicolas/user:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  ports:
  - "8088:8088"
  environment:
    - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker"
  links:
  - discovery-eureka
```

I got this idea from http://www.littlebigextra.com/use-spring-profiles-docker-containers/